# Get DeleteBehavior for Ef Core collections

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I want to know delete actions on all collections in EntityEntry. But it in a private property. I can get it by reflection, but I think is there was a better way?

[image]

```
var entry = context.Entry(this);
foreach(var col in entry.Collections)
{
    var met = col.Metadata as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RuntimeNavigation;
    if (met == null)
        continue;
    var fk = met.ForeignKey;  
    fk.DeleteBehavior ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Metadata` property type is [`INavigationBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.inavigationbase?view=efcore-7.0). However the actual type currently could be either [`INavigation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.inavigation?view=efcore-7.0) or [`ISkipNavigation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iskipnavigation?view=efcore-7.0). The later is for many-to-many skip navigations, and the former is for regular navigations, and is what you need since it provides [`ForeignKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.inavigation.foreignkey?view=efcore-7.0) property of type [`IForeignKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iforeignkey?view=efcore-7.0) which in turn provides access to the desired information. All these interfaces are public (part of the public metadata API).

In other words, cast to appropriate interface and work with it (not sure why they exposed publicly the implementation class, usually they don't), e.g.

```cs
var entry = context.Entry(this);
foreach(var col in entry.Collections)
{
    var nav = col.Metadata as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.INavigation;
    if (nav == null)
        continue;
    var fk = nav.ForeignKey;  
    var deleteBehavior = fk.DeleteBehavior; // here you go
}
```